# /sbin/mkfs.fs acts like a binary file even though it's a symbolic link file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symlink, mkfs

Considering the output from the `ls` command:

```
$ ls -l /sbin/mkfs.ext4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Aug  4 00:10 /sbin/mkfs.ext4 -> mke2fs

$ type mkfs.ext4
mkfs.ext4 is hashed (/sbin/mkfs.ext4)
```

`mkfs.ext4` is a symlink pointing to `mke2fs` command. Nothing strange, all good and fine. Therefore, running `mkfs.ext4`is the same as running `mke2fs`. Notice the curly bracket that I've added in the output of the commands below:

```
$ mke2fs
Usage: {mke2fs} [-c|-l filename] [-b block-size] [-C cluster-size]
                             --sinp--
$ mkfs.ext4
Usage: {mkfs.ext4} [-c|-l filename] [-b block-size] [-C cluster-size]
                             --sinp--
```

Obviously, `mke2fs` uses the name of the file to determine the appropriate filesystem type to make and even to customize its list of options:

```
$ ln -s /sbin/mke2fs mkmk

$ ls -l mkmk 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 direprobs direprobs 12 Aug  8 14:25 mkmk -> /sbin/mke2fs

$ ./mkmk
Usage: mkmk [-c|-l filename] [-b block-size] [-C cluster-size]
                           --sinp--
```

I manged to make an ext2 filesystem using `mkmk`, the symlink which I've made with `ln`. What does `mkmk` mean to `mke2fs`, it should be nothing!

**How does `mke2fs` use filenames from which it's run to determine the filesystem type to make?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `parse_fs_type` function in [`mke2fs.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/mke2fs.c#n1218):

- if a file system type is specified explicitly (using `-t`), use that
- if the tool is running on the Hurd, use “ext2”;
- if the program name is `mke3fs`, use “ext3”;
- if the program name is `mke4fs`, use “ext4”;
- if the program name starts with `mkfs.`, use the suffix;
- otherwise, use the default defined in `/etc/mke2fs.conf`, if any;
- otherwise, use “ext2”, unless a journal is enabled by default, in which case use “ext3”.

The resulting text string is used to find a file system definition in `/etc/mke2fs.conf` (apart from “ext2” which is handled internally).

So your `mkmk` would end up using the ext2 file system type.

Comment: dear @Stephan ,  what "On the Hurd" means ?

Comment: @youness it means if you’re using the Hurd, which is a kernel on which you can run the ext2 tools (but it only supports ext2).

Answer (score 1):

- The `-t` option unconditionally sets the filesystem type, and with that option the only effect of *any* program name is to alter what name for the program is printed out in diagnostic messages as the program runs.
- On the Hurd, ext2 is used as the filesystem type irrespective of the name that the program is invoked as, which again only affects diagnostic messages.
- Otherwise the process' zeroth argument's base name is checked:

  - If invoked with `mke3fs` as the base name it will create an `ext3` filesystem, with a journal as if `-j` had been specified.
  - If invoked with `mke4fs` as the base name it will create an `ext4` filesystem.
  - If the basename begins with the 5 characters `mkfs.` it will use the remaining characters as the filesystem type, unconditionally.  If the base name also happens to be `mkfs.ext3` it creates a journal as if `-j` had been specified.
  - Otherwise, with any other name, it just acts as plain old `mke2fs`, taking the filesystem type from the configuration file and changing from ext2 to ext3 if the `-j` option is supplied.

Most of this can be found in the `mke2fs` and `mke2fs.conf` manuals.  See the explanation of *fs_type* in the latter and the *Description* section of the former.  The only part that is missing from the manuals is that an unrecognized name is effectively `mke2fs`.